# React-reveal Image Slide

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using react reveal and doing an image slide up transition but the image is not showing, I have given the code below as well as the output image. I have added a picture which shows whats happening. the link in the picture was supposed to be an image but it's showing just `Link`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Reveal from 'react-reveal';
import 'animate.css/animate.css';

const generateBlocks = ({blocks}) =>{
    if(blocks){
        return blocks.map((item)=>{

            const styles = {
                background:`url('/images/blocks/${item.image}') no-repeat `
            }

            return(
                <Reveal key={item.id} effect="animated fadeInUp"
                className={`item ${item.type}`}>

                 <div className="veil"></div>
                    <div
                        className="image"
                        style={styles} >

                        </div>
                        <div className="title">
                            <Link to={item.link}>{item.title}</Link>
                        </div>
                 </Reveal>
            )
        })
    }

}

const Blocks = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div className ="home_blocks">
            {generateBlocks(props)}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Blocks;][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heve you tried to import the right component from `Reveal`:

```js
import Reveal from 'react-reveal/Reveal';
```

Have a look into the Documentation: https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/custom/